# Htaccess - Rewrite png to php file

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently use `trans.png.php?id=1&campaign=test` to track my newsletter campaigns.

I want to use trans.png instead as it's the src of an img tag.

How can i do this in htaccess? Also is there any way I can disguise the get variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule /([0-9a-z]+)/([0-9a-z]+)\.png /trans.png.php?id=$2&campaign=$1
```

Then a URL of

`/campaigntest/123.png`

would translate to

`trans.png.php?id=123&campaign=campaigntest`